# cannot find function `start_app` in crate `yew`

Tags: rust, yew

I'm trying to write a simple Rust web programming with Yew, this is main.rs source code :

```
use lat12::App;
fn main() {
    yew::start_app::<App>();
}
```

and this is a simple library :

```
use yew::prelude::*;

#[function_component(App)] 
pub fn app() -> Html {
    html! {
        <h1>{"Welcome to Rust in Yew using library"}</h1>
    }
}
```

and this is cargo.toml :

```
[package]
name = "lat12"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
yew = "0.20.0"
```

If I change version of yew to : "0.19.3" it can run smoothly, but if I use newest version ("0.20.0") it can't run with error message : "cannot find function `start_app` in crate `yew`",..... what should I do ?

Comment: The docs for 0.20.0 have this `yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();`. Can you see if it works? https://docs.rs/yew/0.20.0/yew/index.html

Comment: It now turned to "could not find `Renderer` in `yew`"

Comment: I have read that doc and checked it carefully, comparing to my code.

Comment: Can you try enabling the `csr` feature for `yew` in `Cargo.toml`? https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#dependency-features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [0.19.0 to 0.20.0 migration guide](https://github.com/yewstack/yew/blob/03cd37f1eab039f47b7f919ff1df59fff5b9f01c/website/docs/migration-guides/yew/from-0_19_0-to-0_20_0.mdx):

> ### Yew Renderer
>
> `start_app*` has been replaced by `yew::Renderer`.
>
> You need to enable feature `csr` to use `yew::Renderer`.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
yew = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["csr"] }
```

Use this to mount your App to a custom root element:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
/// init and start app on given root html element
pub fn init_app(
    root: web_sys::Element,
) {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::with_root(
        root,
    )
    .render();
}
```

Your html page should have a div element with id:

```
<div id="app" />
<script type="module">
  import init, { init_app } from "./pkg/app.js";
  var app_element = document.getElementById("app");
  init().then(async () => {
    try {
      init_app(app_element);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  });
</script>
```